Is a ring buffer that waits on empty or full still considered lock-free?
I have a single-producer single-consumer ring buffer that just uses a pair of atomics to keep track of the reading and writing position. When trying to write when full or trying to read when empty, an error code is returned. This is lock-free. Would it be wait-free too?
If I made a version that waits on a pair or semaphores or a spinlock for writing on full and reading on empty, would it no longer be considered lock-free? If not, is it possible to write a lock-free data structure that waits for data or space to be available?
I'm unsure how the line gets drawn in these situations.

Your question heading suggests waiting operations while the body of your question does the opposite. Please fix. I'd also avoid using non-obvious initialisms such as SPSC. (You could just write "single-reader, single-writer" instead I guess.)

While lock-freedom and wait-freedom is sometimes an attribute given to individual data structures, it's not really correct in a bigger picture.
A complete system with a defined start state and goal state (or a set of such concurrent states) can be described as lock-free or wait-free depending on whether or not there exists system-wide guaranteed progress or per-thread guaranteed progress respectively for the system.
Your data structure could be used in such a system, and it depends on the system whether the error conditions "queue full" or "queue empty" can occur or not, and if they do occur whether or not that's problematic.
So you have two options:

Expand the scope of your problem to a larger system in which these error conditions either never occur, or if they do occur that they do not form a problem.

Reduce the scope of your problem such that you define these error conditions to never occur, or that simply getting an error message back is considered the expected behavior.



Im not comfortrable with the line basically being definitional. Its seems like you can then just define yourself into being wait free.

@JasonNordwick For a sufficiently useless system, you can always do that, yes. However I disagree with calling it merely definitional, the problem is getting the most powerful and useful system while maintaining wait-freedom. Note that in case #2 you did get wait-freedom, but in return had to accept the error conditions. There's always a trade-offl

My point was more that waiting or not waiting doesn't change the operation or the time it takes to complete really. If the queue is full, you need to wait until something is read regardless - sure you can go off and do something else and return later, but if that something else isn't helping read from the queue you are still stuck on it. If you have no other work to do. (NB: ChatGPT actually got this wrong when I asked telling me that using a spinlock would make it lock-free.)
